# Let $K$ be a field with $\mathbb{Q} \subset K \subset \mathbb{C}$ and $[K:\mathbb{Q}]$ odd

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory

Let $K$ be a field with $\mathbb{Q} \subset K \subset \mathbb{C}$ and $[K:\mathbb{Q}]$ odd.

1. If $K/\mathbb{Q}$ is Galois, prove that $K$ is contained in $\mathbb{R}$.
2. Find an extension with $[K:\mathbb{Q}]=3$ with $K$ not contained in $\mathbb{R}$.

I am looking for a **hint** on each part. For part 1, I was trying to make an argument with indices: $[\mathbb{C}:\mathbb{R}]=2$, so that $[\mathbb{C}:K]$ must be even. This does not use Galois though...

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint for 1:** If a group has an element of order $2$, then its cardinality is even. When does the automorphism *"complex conjugation"* on a field $K\subset\mathbb{C}$ have order $2$? Now just remember the fundamental theorem of Galois theory.

**Hint for 2:** What is the classic first example of a non-Galois field extension that anyone sees in abstract algebra? Now modify that slightly.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. If $K$ is not contained in $\mathbb{R}$, then complex conjugation has order 2, which implies that the order of the automorphism group is even. Obtain a contradiction by the fundamental theorem of Galois theory. Does $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_3\sqrt[3]{2})/\mathbb{Q}$ work for part 2?

Comment: @Michael: Yup, that's exactly right on all counts.